# Android code for Fastest Way to retrieve data from web server to android! Native method or 3rd party library?

Tags: android

I am using an `AsyncTask` to download a JSON string from  webserver.
While debugging the code I realized that the time taken to transfer control  from the function call in background is taking too much time.

```
public class Downlog extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    // ...
}
```

After entering in background the data downloaded a little faster.
I want to know how to download the data **fast**

Comment: use retrofit 2  for getting data from web server. It is faster than asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definetely Third party library (if you don't want reinvent the wheel :) )